# How to automatically input an array formula as string with more than 255 characters in length into an excel cell using VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

My codes work for non-array formulas, but when I try it as an array formula, it ends up pasting the whole line of code instead of the result it should give out. This is how it looks like:

[image]

My VBA code is as shown below (no need to read whole code):

```
Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 20) = "{=IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!D$2:D$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))=""Extra"",P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "*INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8,IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))>0,IF(AI" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "=""Sunday"",0,IF(OR(AF2>=24,AF2<=8)=TRUE," & _
        "(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/2)/(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AC$2:AC$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ">='Payroll Tables and Settings'!Z$2:Z$538,IF(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AA$2:AA$538,1)),0))-INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AB$2:AB$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ">='Payroll Tables and Settings'!Z$2:Z$538,IF(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AA$2:AA$538,1)),0)))" & _
        "-IF(DTR!AI" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "=""Sunday"",0,IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")<8,IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=0,(8-SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "))*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8),0),0))," & _
        "(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/2)/(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AG$2:AG$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ">='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AD$2:AD$538,IF(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AE$2:AE$538,1)),0))-INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AF$2:AF$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ">='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AD$2:AD$538,IF(DTR!C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AE$2:AE$538,1)),0)))" & _
        "-IF(DTR!AI" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "=""Sunday"",0,IF(SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ")<8,IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(C" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$1048576,0)),0)=0,(8-SUM(DTR!P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ":S" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "))*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8),0),0)))),IF(Z" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ">0,0,IF(AI" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "=""Sunday"",0,P" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & "*INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8))))}"
```

After trying `Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 20).FormulaArray = ...`:

[image]

Latest Attempt:

```
With Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 20)
        .FormulaArray = "=IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!D$2:D$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))=""Extra"",P2*INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8,2424)"
        .Replace "2424", "IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))>0, IF(AI2=""Sunday"",0, IF(OR(AF2>=24,AF2<=8)=TRUE,1111+2222+3333,b.)),4444+5555+6666)"
        .Replace "1111", "(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/2)"
        .Replace "+2222", "/(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AC$2:AC$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!Z$2:Z$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AA$2:AA$538,1)),0))+8888)"
        .Replace "+8888)", "-INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AB$2:AB$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!Z$2:Z$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AA$2:AA$538,1)),0)))"
        .Replace "+3333", "IF(SUM(DTR!P2:S2)<8,IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(C2,'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$104857,0)),0)=0,(8-SUM(DTR!P2:S2))*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$104857,0))/8),0),0)"
        .Replace "4444", "(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/2)"
        .Replace "+5555", "/(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AG$2:AG$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AD$2:AD$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AE$2:AE$538,1)),0))+1212)"
        .Replace "+1212)", "-INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AF$2:AF$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AD$2:AD$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AE$2:AE$538,1)),0)))"
        .Replace "+6666", "IF(SUM(DTR!P2:S2)<8,IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(C2,'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$104857,0)),0)=0,(8-SUM(DTR!P2:S2))*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$104857,0))/8),0),0)"
End With
```

Still does not work with the same run-time error as shown above

Working Code (thanks to Chris Mack):

```
With Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 20)
        .FormulaArray = "=IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!D$2:D$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))=""Extra"",P2*7777/8,2424)"
        .Replace "7777", "INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))"
        .Replace "2424", "IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))>0, IF(AI2=""Sunday"",0, IF(OR(AF2>=24,AF2<=8)=TRUE,1111+2222+3333,4444+5555+6666)),3434)"
        .Replace "1111", "(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/2)"
        .Replace "+2222", "/(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AC$2:AC$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!Z$2:Z$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AA$2:AA$538,1)),0))+8888)"
        .Replace "+8888)", "-INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AB$2:AB$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!Z$2:Z$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AA$2:AA$538,1)),0)))"
        .Replace "+3333", "-IF(SUM(DTR!P2:S2)<8,IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(C2,'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$104857,0)),0)=0,(8-SUM(DTR!P2:S2))*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$104857,0))/8),0),0)"
        .Replace "4444", "(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/2)"
        .Replace "+5555", "/(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AG$2:AG$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AD$2:AD$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AE$2:AE$538,1)),0))+1212)"
        .Replace "+1212)", "-INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AF$2:AF$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AD$2:AD$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AE$2:AE$538,1)),0)))"
        .Replace "+6666", "-IF(SUM(DTR!P2:S2)<8,IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(C2,'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$104857,0)),0)=0,(8-SUM(DTR!P2:S2))*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$104857,0))/8),0),0)"
        .Replace "3434", "IF(Z2>0,0,IF(AI2=""Sunday"",0,P2*INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/8))"
End With
```

Comment: Check the length of your formula. FormulaArray is limited to 255 chars I believe.

Comment: Based on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-formulaarray-property-excel, yea it does have a limit.. I have 2,130 characters :( but I cannot make it any shorter. Is there another way?

Comment: So why ask the question? There is a workaround.

Comment: I actually saw the web page after I posted this question and I didn't notice the character limit until you mentioned it. What workaround is that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 20).FormulaArray = ...
```

Update:

With regards to overcoming the limit when setting the FormulaArray property, one way to get around this is to split your formula into components and then use an alias to represent them. You can then replace the alias with the actual formula string.

Two rules:

1. At each stage your formula must respect the syntax rules of Excel formulas.
2. Each replacement string must be less than or equal to 255 characters in length.

(Update: Per https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/working-with-range-formulaarray-in-vba/: "If you are using A1 notation then the R1C1 equivalent must be less than 255 characters.")

Good candidates for individual components are any sections of the formula that produce a value to be used against another value via an operator (e.g., addition, multiplication, greater than). So if you can get the initial formula you enter looking something like the following you'll be on the right track (you could even use 'Evaluate Formula' to get some ideas for this, as it will evaluate components within your formula and show you each step).

```
{=IF(FirstPart=SecondPart,ThirdPart*FourthPath,FifthPart)}
```

Again, remember that each of these parts must be less than or equal to 255 characters in length. If they aren't, it's usually the case that they can be broken down into further components.

Example:

```
Sub OvercomeFormulaArrayLimit()

    Selection.FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(A2:A9=12,IF(B2:B9=23,C2:C9)))+XYZ"

    For r = 1 To 10

        Selection.Replace "XYZ", "SUM(IF(Sheet1!A2:A9=12,IF(Sheet1!B2:B9=23,Sheet1!C2:C9)))+XYZ"

    Next

    Selection.Replace "XYZ", "SUM(IF(Sheet1!A2:A9=12,IF(Sheet1!B2:B9=23,Sheet1!C2:C9)))"

End Sub
```

So in your code, an example would be:

```
With Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 20)

    .FormulaArray = "=IF(replExtra=""Extra"" ..."
    .Replace "replExtra", "INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!D$2:D$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B" & Total_Rows_Formulas + 1 & ",'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))"
    'etc.

End With
```

A working solution, based on your code above:

```
With Worksheets("DTR").Cells(Total_Rows_Formulas + 1, 20)
        .FormulaArray = "=IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!D$2:D$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))=""Extra"",P2*7777/8,2424)"
        .Replace "7777", "INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))"
        .Replace "2424", "IF(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))>0, IF(AI2=""Sunday"",0, IF(OR(AF2>=24,AF2<=8)=TRUE,1111+2222+3333,b.)),4444+5555+6666)"
        .Replace "1111", "(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/2)"
        .Replace "+2222", "/(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AC$2:AC$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!Z$2:Z$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AA$2:AA$538,1)),0))+8888)"
        .Replace "+8888)", "-INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AB$2:AB$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!Z$2:Z$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AA$2:AA$538,1)),0)))"
        .Replace "+3333", "IF(SUM(DTR!P2:S2)<8,IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(C2,'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$104857,0)),0)=0,(8-SUM(DTR!P2:S2))*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$104857,0))/8),0),0)"
        .Replace "4444", "(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!F$2:F$1048576,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$1048576,0))/2)"
        .Replace "+5555", "/(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AG$2:AG$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AD$2:AD$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AE$2:AE$538,1)),0))+1212)"
        .Replace "+1212)", "-INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!AF$2:AF$538,MATCH(1,IF(DTR!C2>='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AD$2:AD$538,IF(DTR!C2<='Payroll Tables and Settings'!AE$2:AE$538,1)),0)))"
        .Replace "+6666", "IF(SUM(DTR!P2:S2)<8,IF(IFERROR(INDEX('Holidays Table'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(C2,'Holidays Table'!A$2:A$104857,0)),0)=0,(8-SUM(DTR!P2:S2))*(INDEX('Payroll Tables and Settings'!B$2:B$104857,MATCH(DTR!B2,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!A$2:A$104857,0))/8),0),0)"
End With
```

Comment: Tried it it errors. Perhaps it has to be a range instead of a cell? I'll try using a range. Using `Range("T2").FormulaArray` gives the same error as well

Comment: The formula works because when I press ctrl+shift+enter the value is returned correctly

Comment: As a high-rep user you should know that code-only answers are flagged as **low-quality posts**. Please provide some explanation why this solves the problem of OP.

Comment: @MarcSantos I've updated my answer to address this error.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this out in a while

Comment: What is considered a stage?: "At each stage your formula must respect the syntax rules of Excel formulas."

Comment: Basically, every time you make a replacement within your formula - you'll probably need to do a few for the formula you posted. So there'll be a few `Replace` commands, and after each of these, Excel must still be able to read it as a formula (otherwise you'll get an error).

Comment: Okay I kind of get what you mean now i'll try it out

Comment: I've edited the question to add what i've tried although i'm absolutely clueless on where I went wrong

Comment: I'm not sure about why your `End With` isn't being picked up, but we can look into that later (for now get rid of the `With` stuff and prefix all of the commands with that cell reference). I've updated my answer to provide more clarity on how to break your formula down.

Comment: I believe the error is due to the error inside the code. I think I understand now what #1 means. As soon each value is replaced, the cell should be computationally valid else it will error. Will revise accordingly

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156803/discussion-between-marc-santos-and-chris-mack).

Comment: For some reason it wasn't liking your first line, despite it being less than 255 characters. I'm going to investigate this, but in the meantime, I've posted a working solution in my answer.

Comment: Per https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/working-with-range-formulaarray-in-vba/: "If you are using A1 notation then the R1C1 equivalent must be less than 255 characters. I picked this information up from MS MVP Rory Archibald." I imagine it was something to do with this.

Comment: @ChrisMack Thanks a bunch i'll go check it out soon. Yeah perhaps that is the problem some of the lines in the .Replace portions have 252 characters which is a little below the limit perhaps that's why

Comment: In the working solution, the .Replace "+3333" and .Replace "+6666" portions did not replace accordingly. The numbers are still there but other than that it was turned into an array formula which is good. I'll try to see why. Edit: After checking the character count, the replace string is around 254 characters long for both (including spaces). Maybe the R1C1 equivalent led to an excess of 255

Comment: I'd imagine maybe you need to leave the "+" in and just replace the digits? (Or add a "+" at the start of the replacement string.)

Comment: There was a missing "-" sign in the replace string. After that I would say it should work. Thanks for the help after 2 days I finally got off this