# VBA Excel String concatenation upper than max length, How to?

Tags: excel, vba, string

I need to concat a variable set of strings to create a formul to write in excel.

The Len(str) function has the correct answer of 383 characters but the real string is truncated at 255 char. How can i concat strings with a length upper to 255 char?

The example code below.

```
Dim tot As String
tot = "="
For i = 0 To UserDefinitedArray.Size
    tot = tot & "'Sheet" & UserDefinitedArray.Item(i).id &"'!" & UserDefinitedArray.Item(i).cell 
    If(i <> UserDefinitedArray.Size -1 ) Then
       tot = tot & "+" 
    End If
Next i

output_sheet.Range("A1").FormulaLocal = tot
```

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of object is this`UserDefinitedArray`? The concatenation itself should work for much more characters than you need in this case... How did you deduce that the obtained string is trucate at 255 characters?

Comment: This seems an Excel limitation 255, see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_archive/rangeformulaarray-limited-to-255-chars/b9dbd2fe-358d-44f0-8cf6-b8b58b93f570

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46743019/11683?

Comment: @FaneDuru UserDefinedArray is An User Defined Object Len(tot) give me 383 but the real string that i want to write into formula cell is  truncated and give me an error

Comment: @jacouh and what i can do to write a formula tha has more than 255 chars?

Comment: A formula may accept 8,192 characters ([see here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)). It looks to be a limitation of `FormulaArray`... But, why do you use `FormulaLocal`? It my have the same limitation (not documented). Do you have some localization in the sheet naming? Try, please using `Formula` instead and see what's happening...